# Bootstrap 4 collapsed navbar background color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to change background color of collapsed navbar in **bootstrap 4 alpha v6**. Of course I want to change the background color of **whole navbar**.

So the question is any class responsible for navbar collapsing? The only div I found so far is `#navbarSupportedContent` but it's only the content of ul in navbar (so it does not change the color of whole navbar). I can check in jquery if the navbar is collapsed then change the background color, but I would like to know if I can do it simply in css.

In addition to that I would like to say that the navbar default color is transparent, that's why I want to change it's color when it's collapsed.

---

I have also next question what's the class responsible for navbar toggler icon in BS4? I'm asking because I would like to change the color of the icon. I've already found and tried the following:

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  color:white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Bootstrap v5 update**

Here's a Bootstrap 5 CSS walkthrough covering modifications of `.navbar` itself, inside links and hamburger button (all avoiding `!important` which should be used only as last override resort):

```css
/* change navbar background */
nav.navbar {
  background: transparent;
}

/* change navbar-brand color */
.navbar a.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}

/* change navbar-brand color on hover */
.navbar a.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: green;
}

/*  change navbar li colors, also active one but not disabled one */
.navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a.nav-link {
  color: white;
}

/* change navbar-toggler inside lines color (stroke) */
.navbar-light span.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='yellow' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  color: white;
}

/* change hamburger button border color */
.navbar-light button.navbar-toggler {
  border-color: yellow;
}

/* change navbar background on collapse */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  nav.navbar {
    background: lightgray;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

**v4 original answer.**

```css
/* change navbar background */
nav.navbar {
  background: transparent;
}
/* change navbar-brand color */
.navbar a.navbar-brand {
  color: white;
}
/* change navbar-brand color on hover */
.navbar a.navbar-brand:hover {
  color: green;
}
/*  change navbar li colors, also active one but not disabled one */
.navbar ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a.nav-link {
  color: white;
}
/* change navbar-toggler inside lines color (stroke) */
.navbar-light span.navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='yellow' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  color: white;
}
/* change hamburger button border color */
button.navbar-toggler.navbar-toggler-right {
  border-color: yellow;
}
/* change navbar background on collapse */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  nav.navbar {
    background: lightgray;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Okay, the navbar collapse icon works perfect, but the case is that my background color at the beginning is transparent and then if someone will collapse it then the background color should change.

Comment: Great, thank you. What a shame that I did not think about it.

Answer (score 3):

> "...but the case is that my background color at the beginning is
>   transparent and then if someone will collapse it then the background
>   color should change."

I did like this:

```
<style>
.navbar { 
    background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar.collapse {
    display:flex;
}
.navbar.collapsing,
.navbar.show {
    background:white !important;
}
</style>



<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbarSupportedContent">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
       <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent">
   </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked form me:

```
    .navbar-collapse {
    background-color: white;
}
```