# separating the collapsed and uncollapsed bootstrap 4 navbar menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

When building a bootstrap 4 navbar menu, I'm trying to style only the responsive menu after you click the toggle button; however, I'm noticing that there's only 1 css selector for the uncollapsed and collapsed UL.

I'm working with wordpress so the UL in my case is the boostrap walker nav but I created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/NGOF15/pen/MOpXQL) to demonstrate the issue I've come across with static html.

I need a separate UL or the UL to be outside the container for when the toggle button is clicked so I can style it accordingly (in my case yellow bg) and the only way I've been able to even get close is to create another one outside of the container div.

This works when the toggle menu is active but only at around <700px. when it's uncollapsed of coarse there's another nav.

Can I hide the menu outside the container until the toggle menu is active with js or is there a better way to do this?

When researching a solution I came across a similar question [Bootstrap 4 collapsed navbar background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896043/bootstrap-4-collapsed-navbar-background-color) but it didn't work

```
/* change navbar background on collapse */
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  nav.navbar {
    background: lightgray;
  }
}
```

I feel like this is something that should have came up sometime before but I can't find a solution anywhere. I hope my question was concise enough for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed to have found the answer to my question. I used media queries to only target the navbar when it's at the width I needed and add styles. Instead of separating the divs I found a really cool solution that worked perfectly to get the full width bg color I needed. https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/